# Stacked barplot similar to conditional density

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have the following example dataset

```
dump.stack<-structure(list(vanilla = c(16438L, 15877L, 16141L, 15490L, 15468L
), berry = c(27235L, 26692L, 25964L, 25762L, 24961L), orange = c(15825L, 
16278L, 16413L, 16714L, 16881L), lemon = c(40502L, 41153L, 41482L, 
42034L, 42690L), age = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24)), .Names = c("vanilla", 
"berry", "orange", "lemon", "age"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each `age` the total number of answers sums up to 100000. I would like to graph this using stacked barplot with `age` in X axis and the proportion/percentage of individuals in each flavor in the Y axis.

I tried `barplot(as.matrix(dump.stack))` without any success. I come to think that `barplot` and `cdplot` require a tranformation of the data, but I can't figure how.

How can I do it using stacked barpots? Also is it possible to graph this using `cdplot()`(since statistically speaking the graph would be a conditional density).

I would prefare base R but if it is not possible I would also accept ggplot2 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For base R:

```
mm = melt(dump.stack, id='age')
mm$percent = mm$value*100/100000
mm=mm[,c(1,2,4)]
barplot(with(mm3, tapply(value, list(variable,age), sum)), legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

EDIT: Same result can also be obtained with following code:

```
rownames(dump.stack)=dump.stack$age
dump.stack = dump.stack[,-5]
dump.stack = dump.stack/1000
barplot(t(dump.stack), legend=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mm = melt(dump.stack, id='age')
mm$percent = mm$value*100/100000
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mm)+geom_bar(aes(x=age, y=percent, fill=variable), stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if its possible with base R or with cdplot?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your request to to an area-plot with `cdplot` (or other base strategy)... just use the transpose of the data elements. The help page for `cdplot` says it's similar to `spineplot`. `spineplot` takes its individual columns in .... er, rows.

```
spineplot(t(dump.stack[-5]))
```

[image]

I think it has the distinct advantage over barcharts that the width of the columns is informative. You can also do a further transpose (to keep the input a matrix) and have each column be a separate age (which might have been what you wanted in the beginning):

```
    png(); spineplot(t(t(dump.stack[-5])), 
      xaxlabels=dump.stack[[5]], ylab="Preferences", xlab="Ages"); dev.off()
```

[image]